# Remove consecutive duplicate values in a string

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a program so that when a string such as "cccaaaattt" is entered the output will be "cat"

Here is my code so far:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    string str = "";//create an empty string variable named str
    std::cout << "What word do you want to remove duplicate characters from?";
    cin >> str; //fill the str variable with the word the user whants to remove duplicate consecutive characters from
    char current;//create a new char variable named current
    char lastChar;//create a new char variable named lastChar for the previos character in the string

for (int i = 1; i < str.length(); i++){ //iterate through until it reaches the end of the string
    lastChar = str[i - 1]; //set lastChar to the previos char in the string
    current = str[i];//set current to the current char in the string
    if (lastChar == current){//if the lastChar and the current are equal (the string has two consecutive characters
        str.erase(i,1);//erase the current character
    }

}
cout << str << endl; //display the new string
system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

I commented on what I thought the code would have done.

It does not remove the right amount of character making my output "ccaatt"

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I started retagging it as C++/CLI but tbh it's almost pure C++ except for `args` (which is unused)

Comment: Hint: when you have 4 consecutive identical characters, you have 2 pairs. You correctly remove the second half of each pair.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One extremely easy and efficient way to do this in C++ is to use [`std::unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) from the algorithm library and the [`erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) function of [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string x("xxbbbbccccczzzzxxxx");
    x.erase(std::unique(x.begin(), x.end()), x.end());
    std::cout << x << "\n";
}
```

This will output:

> xbczx

Comment: I new there would be something simple like this. Thank you. Your user name is relevant :)

Answer (score 1):

Whereas using `std::unique` does the job, your error is that you increase your counter after `erase`. The fixed implementation:

```
for (int i = 1; i < str.length(); /* No increment here */ ) {
    if (str[i - 1] == str[i]) {
        str.erase(i, 1);
    } else {
        ++i;
    }
}
```